# How are oracle clobs internally handled?

Tags: database, oracle, clob

I have a column (CLOB type) in a database which holds json strings. These size of these json strings can be quite variable. In the case where these strings are less than 4000 characters I have heard that Oracle treats these CLOBs as VARCHAR internally. However, I am curious how exactly this process works. My interest is in the performance and ability to visually see json being stored.

If a CLOB in the DB has 50 characters does Oracle treat this single object as VARCHAR2(50) ? Do all CLOBs stored in the column need to be less than 4000 characters for Oracle to treat the whole column as a VARCHAR ? How does this all work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle does not *always* treat short `CLOB` values as `VARCHAR2` values.  It only does this if you allow it to do so, using the `CLOB` storage option of `ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW`.  E.g.,

```
create table clob_test (
    id      number NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    v1      varchar2(60),
    c1      clob
) lob(c1) store as (enable storage in row);
```

In this case, Oracle will store the data for `C1` in the table blocks, right next to the values for `ID` and `V1`.  It will do this as long as the length of the `CLOB` value is less than *close to* 4000 bytes (i.e., 4000 minus system control information that takes space in the `CLOB`).

In this case, the `CLOB` data will be read like a `VARCHAR2` (e.g., the storage `CHUNK` size becomes irrelevant).

If the `CLOB` grows too big, Oracle will quietly move it out of the block into separate storage, like any big `CLOB` value.

> > If a CLOB in the DB has 50 characters does Oracle treat this single object as VARCHAR2(50)?

Basically, if the `CLOB` was created with `ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW`.  This option cannot be altered after the fact.  I wouldn't count on Oracle treating the `CLOB` *exactly* like a `VARCHAR2` in every respect.  E.g., there is system control information stored in the in-row `CLOB` that is not stored in a `VARCHAR2` column.  But for many practical purposes, including performance, they're very similar.

> > Do all CLOBs stored in the column need to be less than 4000 characters for Oracle to treat the whole column as a VARCHAR?

No.  It's on a row-by-row basis.

> > How does this all work?

I explained what I know as best I could.  Oracle doesn't publish its internal algorithms.

Comment: Thanks. However, I read that inline storage is the default setting for LOBs and so, I don't need to explicitly ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW ?

Comment: Yes, it is the default.  I like to explicitly set values that my design is depending on, if for no other reason that it gives me a line of code in the DDL to comment.